# Visual Studio Watch windows

Tags: visual-studio

I am looking for the specific reason that there are several windows called "Watch 1", "Watch 2" etc.

It's the same with "Find Results 1" and Find Results 2" but in this case I can understand why you would want to keep the last find results to use side by side with the new search.

But I can't understand why anybody would need two watch windows. I can't find information about it anywhere and am just curious.

Answer (score 1):

For me having multiple watch windows helps me in debugging multiple files. E.g. in "watch 1" I am watching at values from File A, while I can switch fast to the most interesting variables in File B, when I am debugging that.

Comment: Yea sure that makes some sense :)